# Making non-linear commits as linear in git

Tags: git, github, gitkraken

I'm trying to learn git by trying different commands.

I'm using "GitKraken" to visualize how the git commit "graph" changes as and when I try different commands.

At one point , I used "git reset --hard HEAD~2" to go back to the previous 2 commits.

Till that time the graph was linear. When I made changes to my file, staged them and committed them, the new commit became non-linear somehow.

I wish to make that particular commit linear along with the other commits. Please refer to the image link mentioned

[Git Non-Linear state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHVWU.png)

Comment: Try `git rebase $commit`. `$commit` is `Process 2 added by UtileHomme1`.

Comment: I tried it on `Hello Jatin (the commit after Process 2)`. I did this on my own before I saw your comment. I have this now!!

[link](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img924/2558/azTTuA.jpg)